# Derivation of transcondutance gm using Taylor expansion

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

From the fist page of the [lecture](http://www.prenhall.com/howe3/microelectronics/pdf_folder/lectures/mwf/lecture12.fm5.pdf), there is a derivation of transconductance of MOSFET using Taylor expansion.

As seen from the picture bellow, drain current is a function of vGS, vDS and vBS.
iD is a function of three variables here. However, in Taylor expansion around DC operating point (VGS, VDS, VBS) the author didn't take vDS, vBS as variables.
So iD is just like a function of vGS only.

I am wondering why they can do that?
This seems to be wrong to me.
Could anyone confirm?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the introduction, all other voltages are held constant:

> Derivation: consider for example the relationship of the increment in drain
>   current due to an increment in gate-source voltage when the MOSFET is
>   saturated-- with all other voltages held constant.

An for this reason only the change of the gate-source voltage is considered.

Of course to extend this model a similar derivation will be done for vds and vbs resulting in gds and gmbs.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. You are right. I am able to derive all the three transconductance parameters now.